# import bootstrap variables in my style.sass issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to import bootstrap 4 beta variables partial in my style.sass but when i compile i get the following error:

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^ Error: node_modules\bootstrap\scss_variables.scss Error: argument `$color` of `darken($color, $amount)` must be a color
>
> ```
>    Backtrace:
>     node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss:168, in function `darken`
>     node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss:168
>     on line 168 of node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
> ```
>
> > > $link-hover-color:      darken($link-color, 15%) !default;    ------------------------^
>
> ```
> at options.error (C:\Users\Giannis\Desktop\np-lab\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:291:26)
> ```

here is my code:

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables"

body
  background-color: red
```

Any ideas what is going on? 
thanks

Comment: Have you defined `$brand-primary` or `$link-color` before importing the variables file and if yes, to which value(s)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Before importing variables file, you have to import functions.scss. Darken function is defined in it.

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
<!--your styles here-->
```

Comment: Great! that worked, can you illustrate why we need to import functions?

Comment: Thank you. This replaced the workaround of having to import the entire bootstrap scss file which blew up the overall css file.